# NestJS Gateway cannot receive messages from Microservices?

Tags: microservices, nestjs, gateway

I'm trying to pass a message from a Microservice to an event.gateway (@WebSocketGateway()) but the @EventPattern() in the event.gateway is not receiving any message.

Basically how a Microservice can send messages to an event.gateway?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe is not the perfect one, but solves the subject.

in the event.gateway I add the **@Controller**

```
...
@Controller('something')
@WebSocketGateway()
...
```

and then in event.module put EventsGateway to the *controllers*

```
...
  controllers: [EventsGateway],
  providers: [EventsGateway]
...
```

Solved, I can receive events from microservices in the gateway.